# Getting nil from Enum Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift-optionals

I have created a class

```
class NewTabContainerModal {

var newContainerDate = Date()
var newContainerSelectedFilter : NewAllErrorFIlter = .Yearly

func resetModal () {
    newContainerSelectedFilter = .Yearly
    newContainerDate = Date()
}
}
```

I have created an enum to get the values from it

```
enum NewAllErrorFIlter : String {
case Monthly = "2"
case Yearly = "1"
case Daily = "3"
}
```

Now in my **ViewController** class I have created a variable

```
var newContainerModal: NewTabContainerModal?
```

And in **viewWillAppear** I am trying to print the value of the enum like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 

 let newContainerModelData = newContainerModal?.newContainerSelectedFilter
 print(newContainerModelData)
}
```

but it is giving me nil instead of yearly value. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help?

Comment: Are you sure your modal is instantiated properly? I see that you have it as an optional (meaning it could be nil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `newContainerModal` in your Viewcontroller is `nil` so `newContainerModal?.newContainerSelectedFilter` also gonna be a `nil` change it with

```
var newContainerModal: NewTabContainerModal = NewTabContainerModal()
```

In addition

```
let newContainerModelData = newContainerModal.newContainerSelectedFilter
print(newContainerModelData)
```

will print `Yearly`. to get that value use `newContainerModelData.rawValue`